# Подключение по IP

Tags: ip, curl, php

Есть сервер (для работы используется только ip), и есть сайт-обработчик.
По адресу (значения изменены) http://1.2.3.4:100/all я получаю json массив (если зайти через браузер), а открыть этот адрес через `file()`, `file_get_contents()` или `curl()` -- возвращается пустота.

Гуглил на протяжении 6 часов, ничего не нагуглил, подскажите, как реализовать подключение и получение информации?

P.S. Пытался через js получить (при помощи `$.getJSON()`, `$.post()`, `$.get()`, `$.ajax()`) -- опять ничего.

Comment: Поставьте расширение live http headers (или аналог) и попробуйте воспроизвести выведенные хедеры в программе.

Comment: А если без установки дополнительных расширений?

Comment: В консоли разработчика в хроме посмотрите, куда идут запросы.